# Get the first letter of each word in a string

Tags: php, string

How would I get the first letter of each word for a given string?

```
$string = "Community College District";
$result = "CCD";
```

I found the javascript method but wasn't sure how to convert it to php.

Comment: Do you want to know how to get the first letter of your string, as per how your question is phrased or how to get the first letter of each word, as per your example? If the former: $result = $string[0].

Comment: You're positive that each word is separated by a single space? `What__about__this__sentence?` or `What about.This sentence?`

Comment: Frankly develop your own script in PHP.

Comment: What are the characters that would qualify as separators?  Space, dash, underscore, etc?

Comment: I have the sentence saved in database, so I made sure it doesn't have underscores or dots, just spaces between each other.

Comment: explode the string at white spaces then loop through the result array and because each one is a string you can use $string[0] to get the first character then simply concatenate those.

Comment: @gaurav That question is not consistent with what the asker wants.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

[`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.explode.php) on the spaces, then you use an appropriate substring method to access the first character of each word.

```
$words = explode(" ", "Community College District");
$acronym = "";

foreach ($words as $w) {
  $acronym .= mb_substr($w, 0, 1);
}
```

If you have an expectation that multiple spaces may separate words, switch instead to `preg_split()`

```
$words = preg_split("/\s+/", "Community College District");
```

Or if characters other than whitespace delimit words (`-,_`) for example, use `preg_split()` as well:

```
// Delimit by multiple spaces, hyphen, underscore, comma
$words = preg_split("/[\s,_-]+/", "Community College District");
```

Comment: To the point: `preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/", ucwords(strtolower($string)), $matches);`

Comment: That fails for all multi-byte characters

Answer (score 52):

The best way to accomplish this is with regular expressions.

Lets break down what you want in a logical way: You want every character from the string is at the beginning of a word. The best way to identify those characters is to look for those characters that are preceded by white space.

So we start with a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) for that space character, followed by any character:

```
/(?<=\s)./
```

This will find any character preceded by a space. But - the first character in the string is a character in the string is one you want extract. And because it's the first character in the string, it can't be preceded by a space. So we want to match anything preceded by a space *or* the first character in the string, so we add a [start-of-subject assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#multi):

```
/(?<=\s|^)./
```

Now we are getting closer. But what if the string contains blocks of multiple spaces? What if it contains a space followed by a punctuation character? We probably don't want to match any of those, in fat we probably just want to match letters. We can do that with "any word character" `\w` escape sequence. And we can make are expression case-insensitive using the `i` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) as well as `u` modifier to support utf-8 characters.

So we end up with:

```
/(?<=\s|^)\w/iu
```

But how do we actually use this in PHP? Well we want to *match all* occurrences of the regular expression within the string so we use (you guessed it) [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg-match-all):

```
$string = "Progress in Veterinary Science";

$expr = '/(?<=\s|^)\w/iu';
preg_match_all($expr, $string, $matches);
```

Now we have all the characters we wanted to extract. To construct the result string you show, we need to [join them together again](http://php.net/implode):

```
$result = implode('', $matches[0]);
```

...and we need to ensure that they are [all upper-case](http://php.net/strtoupper):

```
$result = mb_strtoupper($result);
```

And that's really all there is to it.

[See it working](https://3v4l.org/4iZ6L)

---

Here's a slightly compressed version, using the alternative regex from Leigh's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706429/get-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string#comment23103308_16165234) to "capture the initial letters of words separated by hyphens, full stops, etc." (rather than only spaces.)

```
$str="Foo Bar";
preg_match_all('/(?<=\b)\w/iu',$str,$matches);
$result=mb_strtoupper(implode('',$matches[0]));
```

Comment: If you wanted you could also use `(?<=\b)` instead of `(?<=\s|^)`, this would allow you to capture the initial letters of words separated by hyphens, full stops, etc. (basically "non word" characters, those that would not match \w or \W), but could also end up capturing things you don't want.

Comment: Your solution helped a lot! Thank you !

Comment: This should definitely be the answer. Extremely detailed and works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: This helped me, but what about the case of $string = "Progress in Veterinary Science (Brower County)";  the 'B' is dropped.  Any thoughts

Comment: What and where would I need to add to this to get the first three letters of each word? I am needing to use this and the words in use will always have atleast 3 letters so just want to grab 3 from each word.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming the words are all split by spaces, this is a suitable solution:

```
$string = "Progress in Veterinary Science";

function initials($str) {
    $ret = '';
    foreach (explode(' ', $str) as $word)
        $ret .= strtoupper($word[0]);
    return $ret;
}

echo initials($string); // would output "PIVS"
```

Comment: I think $word[0] is faster than substr($word,0,1) so why do you use substr($word,0,1)?

Comment: I'm just not very trusting of strings as arrays. I've had some errors pop up in the past

Comment: Edit: TL;DR: just old habits

Comment: @LeonardChallis I don't know, if _Chen Asraf_ was reffering to this kind of errors, but using `substr($word,0,1)` (or actually -- `mb_substr($word, 0, 1, 'utf-8')`) is an absolute must, if you're operating on multi-byte strings. Using simple `$word[0]` will chop multi-byte character half and give you incorrect initial -- some strange symbol instead of actual letter. If you refer this situation as an error, then there you have your answer! :]

Comment: Any method or way to ignore words like (in, the, of, a ...) and get output as "PVS" instead of "PIVS"

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of `explode` answers. I think using the `strtok` function is a much more elegant and memory-efficient solution:

```
function createAcronym($string) {
    $output = null;
    $token  = strtok($string, ' ');
    while ($token !== false) {
        $output .= $token[0];
        $token = strtok(' ');
    }
    return $output;
}
$string = 'Progress in Veterinary Science';
echo createAcronym($string, false);
```

Here is a more robust and useful function, which supports UTF8 characters and the option to only use the capitalized words:

```
function createAcronym($string, $onlyCapitals = false) {
    $output = null;
    $token  = strtok($string, ' ');
    while ($token !== false) {
        $character = mb_substr($token, 0, 1);
        if ($onlyCapitals and mb_strtoupper($character) !== $character) {
            $token = strtok(' ');
            continue;
        }
        $output .= $character;
        $token = strtok(' ');
    }
    return $output;
}
$string = 'Leiðari í Kliniskum Útbúgvingum';
echo createAcronym($string);
```

Comment: I disagree, your code is massive compared to the explode methods.

Comment: @Dale Well, that tells us more about you than about my code -- aesthetics are a poor way of assessing code. Using `explode` to solve this problem is what would be called a *naïve solution*. It is like using the bubble-sort algorithm just because it is easy to implement.

Comment: @MAssiveAmountsOfCode I disagree why do something in 13 lines of code, that can be achieved in 1 `foreach(explode(' ', $string) as $word) echo $word[0];` ? Easier to understand at a glance, and not a time waster.

Comment: Also what is naive about splitting a string of words separated by a space, by a space? I think your remark tells us that you're a pompous coder that isn't open to code reviews.

Comment: @Dale I did not mean to insult you, or to appear pompous. It is naïve because exploding a string creates an array, where one is not needed. Tokenizing the string is more elegant because you are stepping through the original string, which requires less memory. I am not saying that using `explode` is *wrong* (it gets the job done), but that there is a more elegant say of solving the problem. And I am not using the word "elegant" in an aesthetic way, I am using it in a technical way.

Comment: I agree, this is technically elegant and was a solution to the problem I was searching for where I wanted to take uppercase only characters from a companies name, therefore removing `ltd.` or `corp` etc. except when capitalised. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 10):

As explained by others, classical way consist in iterating over each word of your initial string, reduce the word to its first letter, and combine those first letters together.

Here is a helper method combining the different steps.

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
function getInitials($string = null) {
    return array_reduce(
        explode(' ', $string),
        function ($initials, $word) {
            return sprintf('%s%s', $initials, substr($word, 0, 1));
        },
        ''
    );
}
```

NB : this will return an empty string in case the given string is empty.

`getInitials('Community College District')`

> string 'CCD' (length=3)

`getInitials()`

> string '' (length=0)

`getInitials('Lorem ipsum dolor sic amet')`

> string 'Lidsa' (length=5)

Of course you can add filters to the callback function of `array_reduce()`, such as `strtoupper()` if you prefer only uppercased initials for instance.

Answer (score 9):

*Michael Berkowski*'s (and others) answer, simplified to one line and working correctly on multi-byte characters (i.e. making abbreviation / initials out of non-Latin string):

```
foreach(explode(' ', $words) as $word) $acronym .= mb_substr($word, 0, 1, 'utf-8');
```

Using `mb_substr($word, 0, 1, 'utf-8')`, instead of `$word[0]` seems to be must, if you're working on non-Latin, multi-byte strings and characters, i.e. when using UTF-8 encoded strings.

Answer (score 5):

```
$temp = explode(' ', $string);
$result = '';
foreach($temp as $t)
    $result .= $t[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this

```
preg_match_all('#(?<=\s|\b)\pL#u', $String, $Result);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($Result, 1) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Nice. I got problem with first letter in my code. What character indicates first letter? `<=` ?

Comment: +1 for `\pL`. Could you add a little explanation though? I prefer to teach a man to fish rather than just giving him one ;-)

Comment: @Narek (?<=) this is Positive Lookbehind 
[this detail](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @DaveRandom [here datail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) about this chars

Comment: @Winston *I* know (although I took the KISS approach in my answer), I meant more for the OP ;-) but thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Read [my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71713688/2943403) of why this pattern is doing more work that it needs to.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'I am a String!';
echo implode('', array_map(function($v) { return $v[0]; }, explode(' ', $str)));

// would output IaaS
```

Answer (score 3):

Something I've cooked up.

```
/**
 * Return the first letter of each word in uppercase - if it's too long.
 *
 * @param string $str
 * @param int $max
 * @param string $acronym
 * @return string
 */
function str_acronym($str, $max = 12, $acronym = '')
{
    if (strlen($str) <= $max) return $str;

    $words = explode(' ', $str);

    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        $acronym .= strtoupper(substr($word, 0, 1));
    }

    return $acronym;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function acronym( $string = '' ) {
    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    if ( ! $words ) {
        return false;
    }
    $result = '';
    foreach ( $words as $word ) $result .= $word[0];
    return strtoupper( $result );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the [str_word_count](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) function for this?

1. get each word as a row in an array
2. [reduce](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) that array to the first letter

   $acronym = array_reduce(
       str_word_count("Community College District", 1), 
       function($res , $w){
           return $res  . $w[0]; 
       }
   );

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the original string is properly built (trimmed and without double spaces), this is what I do:

```
$name = 'John Doe';
$initials = implode( '', array_map( function ( $part ) { 
    return strtoupper( $part['0'] );
}, explode( ' ', $name ) ) );
```

Basically, breaking the string into words, extracting & capitalizing the first character of a word, and gluing them back together.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to explode and join them back again .....

```
<?php
$string  = "Progress in Veterinary Science";
$pieces = explode(" ", $string);
$str="";
foreach($pieces as $piece)
{
    $str.=$piece[0];
}    
echo $str; /// it will result into  "PiVS"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Prateeks foundation, here's a simple example with explanations

```
//  initialize variables
$string = 'Capitalize Each First Word In A String';
$myCapitalizedString = '';

//  here's the code
$strs=explode(" ",$string);    
foreach($strs as $str) {
  $myCapitalizedString .= $str[0]; 
}

//  output
echo $myCapitalizedString;  // prints 'CEFWIAS'
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are more number of spaces between two letters in the input string then try this.

```
function first_letter($str)
{
    $arr2 = array_filter(array_map('trim',explode(' ', $str)));
    $result='';
    foreach($arr2 as $v)
    {
        $result.=$v[0];
    }
    return $result;
}

$str="    Let's   try   with    more   spaces       for  fun .   ";

echo first_letter($str);
```

[Demo1](https://3v4l.org/cd9FE)

Alternative of same code

```
function first_letter($str)
{
    return implode('', array_map(function($v) { return $v[0]; },array_filter(array_map('trim',explode(' ', $str)))));;
}

$str="    Let's   try   with    more   spaces       for  fun .   ";

echo first_letter($str);
```

[Demo2](https://3v4l.org/BbKfX)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that gets you the initials of a name and if the initials are only 1 letter then it returns the first 2 letters of the first name.

```
function getNameInitials($name) {

    preg_match_all('#(?<=\s|\b)\pL#u', $name, $res);
    $initials = implode('', $res[0]);

    if (strlen($initials) < 2) {
        $initials = strtoupper(substr($name, 0, 2));
    }

    return strtoupper($initials);
}
```

Comment: Read [my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71713688/2943403) of why this pattern is doing more work that it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$strs=explode(" ",$string);

foreach($strs as $str)
  echo $str[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $arr = explode(" ",$String);

foreach($arr as $s)
{
   echo substr($s,0,1);
}

?>
```

firstly I explode string by spaces then I substr first char.

http://php.net/substr

http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
$string = 'Some words in a string';
$words = explode(' ', $string); // array of word
foreach($words as $word){
    echo $word[0]; // first letter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case that you'll be doing this on large strings (or even directly from file) [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) isn't the best way to do this. Imagine how much memory will get wasted if you have to split string 2MB large into memory.

With little more coding and (assuming `PHP >= 5.0`) you can easily implement PHP's [`Iterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) class that will do exactly this. This will be close to generator in python and long story short, here's the code:

```php
/**
 * Class for CONTINOUS reading of words from string.
*/
class WordsIterator implements Iterator {
    private $pos = 0;
    private $str = '';
    private $index = 0;
    private $current = null;

    // Regexp explained:
    // ([^\\w]*?) - Eat everything non-word before actual word characters
    //              Mostly used only if string beings with non-word char
    // ([\\w]+)   - Word
    // ([^\\w]+?|$) - Trailing thrash
    private $re = '~([^\\w]*?)([\\w]+)([^\\w]+?|$)~imsS';

    // Primary initialize string
    public function __construct($str) {
        $this->str = $str;
    }

    // Restart indexing
    function rewind() {
        $this->pos = 0;
        $this->index = 0;
        $this->current = null;
    }

    // Fetches current word
    function current() {
        return $this->current;
    }

    // Return id of word you are currently at (you can use offset too)
    function key() {
        return $this->index;
    }

    // Here's where the magic is done
    function next() {
        if( $this->pos < 0){
            return;
        }

        $match = array();
        ++$this->index;

        // If we can't find any another piece that matches... Set pos to -1
        // and stop function
        if( !preg_match( $this->re, $this->str, $match, 0, $this->pos)){
            $this->current = null;
            $this->pos = -1;
            return;
        }

        // Skip what we have read now
        $this->current = $match[2];
        $this->pos += strlen( $match[1]) + strlen( $match[2]) + strlen($match[3]);

        // We're trying to iterate past string
        if( $this->pos >= strlen($this->str)){
            $this->pos = -1;
        }

    }

    // Okay, we're done? :)
    function valid() {
        return ($this->pos > -1);
    }
}
```

And if you'll use it on a bit more challenging string:

```php
$a = new WordsIterator("Progress in Veterinary Science. And, make it !more! interesting!\nWith new line.");
foreach( $a as $i){
    echo $i;
    echo "\n";
}
```

Will you get the expected result:

```
Progress
in
Veterinary
Science
And
make
it
more
interesting
With
new
line
```

So you can easily use `$i[0]` to fetch first letter.You probably can see that this is more effective solution than splitting whole string into memory (always use only as little memory as possible). You also could easily modify this solution to work with continuous reading of files etc.

Comment: The `i` and `s` pattern modifiers provide no benefit to this pattern.  I have no idea what `S` is trying to do.  The `[^\\w]` boils down to `\W` and `[\\w]` boils down to `\w`.  For this question, I cannot see anyone being compelled to implement this class when a simple, native `preg_` call will do a fine job.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function initials($string) {
        if(!(empty($string))) {
            if(strpos($string, " ")) {
                $string = explode(" ", $string);
                $count = count($string);
                $new_string = '';
                for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $first_letter = substr(ucwords($string[$i]), 0, 1);
                $new_string .= $first_letter;
            }
            return $new_string;
            } else {
                $first_letter = substr(ucwords($string), 0, 1);
                $string = $first_letter;
                return $string;
            }
        } else {
            return "empty string!";
        }
    }
    echo initials('Thomas Edison');
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  `empty()` is doing more work that is needed here.  `$string` is guaranteed to be declared, so a function-less falsey check would do the same thing.  A `foreach()` instead of `for()` would remove some code bloat and reduce the total number of variables.  This whole snippet is over-engineered.  The check for emptiness is unnecessary and potentially flawed if the string is `0`.  The `else` branch that handles the single-word string is completely unnecessary. Although it works, I don't see any redeeming value in this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I like Reg Expression over any other method of string extraction, but if you are unfamiliar with Reg Ex then hear is a method using the `explode()` PHP function:

```
$string = "David Beckham";
$string_split = explode(" ", $string);
$inititals = $string_split[0][0] . $string_split[1][0];
echo $inititals;
```

Obviously the above code will only work on a name containing two words.

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33080232/1046909 but with multibyte strings support:

```php
if (!function_exists('str_acronym')) {
    function str_acronym(string $str, int $min = -1, string $prefix = null): string
    {
        if (mb_strlen($str) <= $min) {
            return $str;
        };

        $words = explode(' ', $str);

        $acronym = strval($prefix);

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            if ($word = trim($word)) {
                $acronym .= mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($word, 0, 1));
            }
        }

        return $acronym;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that function based on the accepted answer from @Michael Berkowski

```
function buildAcronym($string, $length = 1) {
    $words = explode(" ", $string);
    $acronym = "";
    $length = (self::is_empty($string) || $length <= 0 ? 1 : $length);

    foreach ($words as $i => $w) {
        $i += 1;
        if($i <= $length) {
            $acronym .= $w[0];
        }
    }

    return $acronym;
}
```

The $length parameter determines how many chars you want to display

USAGE:

```
$acronym = buildAcronym("Hello World", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little underwhelmed by the suggested techniques here (despite having so many to choose from).

Assuming your input string is solely composed of whitespace delimited "words" (and you don't need to validate that the first character of each word is an actual letter), you can use this concise, multibyte safe technique to trim all letters after the first letter from each word and also discard the delimiting whitespaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NOrQb))

```
$string = "Let's observe obviously knowledgeable approaches that target helpful items succinctly";

echo preg_replace('~\S\K\S*\s*~u', '', $string);
```

Output:

```
Lookatthis
```

If you want to specifically target "letters", you can use `\p{Ll}` and non-letters with `\P{Ll}` (as replacements for `\S` and `\s`.  The `\K` restarts the fullstring match -- by effect, the matched first matched letter of each word is "set free" before matching more characters to be replaced by the empty string.

---

I see some other approaches on this page that are using lookbehinds to match the first letter of each word with `preg_match_all('~(?<=\s|\b)\pL~u', ...)`, but notice the effect on fringe cases:

```
$string = "Let's check some fringe-cases: like @mentions and email@example";
#matches:  ^   ^ ^     ^    ^      ^      ^     ^        ^   ^     ^
```

I cannot say if these would be desirable results, but if they were, then the pattern could be distilled to `~\b\pL~u` because the word boundary (`\b`) is a zero-length assertion that doesn't require a lookbehind AND it covers every character that `\s` could match.

---

I should also mention that any of the answers on this page that are accessing the first character by its offset (using array-like syntax like `$word[0]`) or `substr()` will fail whenever a multibyte character is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$string  = "Community College District";
echo $result = implode ('',array_map(function ($item) {return strtoupper($item[0]);} , explode(' ', $string)));
```

Comment: $string  = "सामुदायिक कॉलेज जिला"; Try now