# How to get all first character in sentences using PHP?

Tags: php

What I want to do is only get all the first character in the sentences, I knew `substr` can do this, but my `substr` only able to get one character.

I use this code now, but it is only get `H` instead of `HW`

```
substr($string,0,1);
```

what I want is

```
$string = "Hello World";
$result = "HW";
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706429/get-first-letter-of-each-word

Comment: This should be a helpful example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706429/get-first-letter-of-each-word

Comment: are they only separated by space? what about other characters?

Comment: Hi all, the problem in my sentences sometime might be with comma or underscore or other special character, so I cannot use explode empty space

Comment: That being the case, you'll need to specify what kind of input you are expecting in `$string`, and how you want to split it

Comment: I cannot estimate what is the words $string , because the $string is base on user typing and insert to my database, what I do is get all the string base on the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = 'Hello, World!';
$result = '';
foreach (preg_split('#[^a-z]+#i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $word) {
    $result .= $word[0];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/158045

Comment: Thanks WizKid, Its working fine, but the problem is the string can be random, such as $string = "Hello, World"; or $string = "Hello_World"; , if like this, I cannot use explode to check empty space, any idea ?

Comment: I edit and used preg_split for non alphabetic characters instead

Comment: Hi Wizkid, I did not score you because there got error regarding in your code, this is error I get 

" Uninitialized string offset: 0 "

Comment: Missed one thing. Fixed

Comment: @user3678068: I would say that the correct answer is "ab" but if you want to treat digits as being part of words just add 0-9 in the regex

Answer (score 0):

You could easily make a loop that would check if current index of char is capital (using the ctype_upper($char) function). If it's capital, add it to an array or print it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function string_from_first_letter_of_each_word($string){
  $sA = explode(' ', $string); $r = '';
  foreach($sA as $v){
    $r .= substr($v, 0, 1);
  }
  return $r;
}
echo string_from_first_letter_of_each_word('Hello World');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```
$string = "Hello World";
preg_match_all('/^.|(?<=\s)./', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another regex solution:

```
$s = "hello world, it's me";                                                                                                                                                                                   
preg_match_all('/\b\w/', $s, $matches);                                                                                                                                                                        
echo implode('', $matches[0]);
```

prints `hwism`

Comment: Looks like it fail on underscore

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution without `regex`:

```
$yourString = "This is a test";
$yourArray = explode(" ",$yourString);
$firstLetters = "";
foreach($yourArray as $word) {
    $firstLetters .= strtoupper($word[0]);
}

echo $firstLetters; // > TIAT
```