# I was wondering if it is possible to create a unique name of initials and surname generated from a faker database

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

http://prntscr.com/axch7p

Okay so here is a picture of our code for migrating in php. The *'hr_uname'* is unique such that it will take the first letter of the generated *'hr_fname'*, the first letter of the 'hr_mname' (or middle initial), then take the *'hr_lname'* as a whole.

How would I implement this in the seeding code? As I read from other questions, it is possible with pre-defined words with explode ([get first letter of each word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706429/get-first-letter-of-each-word)) which is in this link) which in our case is different since the basis will be from the faker generated data. If for example the generated *fname* *mname* and *lname* will be **Jonas Colorado Fonacier**, how will I implement it in the code for seeding so that in the database it will appear with **Jonas** in the *hr_fname* column, **Colorado** in the *hr_mname* column, and **Fonacier** in the *hr_lname* column, with **jcfonacier** in the *hr_uname* column?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
    $name = 'Jonas Colorado Fonacier';
    $nameArray = explode(' ',$name);
    $hr_fname = $nameArray[0];  // Jonas
    $hr_mname = $nameArray[1];  // Colorado
    $hr_lname = $nameArray[2];  // Fonacier
    $hr_uname = strtolower($hr_fname[0].$hr_mname[0].$hr_lname);    // jcfonacier
?>
```

Comment: Since data will be seeded randomly, how can I implement this code so that it will automatically do this when I run the seeder? I will be using faker as database seeder.

Comment: @JonasEdwinFonacier Please post code of your seeder class.

Comment: Sorry late reply wait I will compose the full code without the code for the unique name

Comment: @JonasEdwinFonacier ok