# Get first letter of each word in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create an "avatar" similar to how Gmail does it where it will take a persons name and get the first letter of each word to create an avatar of sorts.

I have followed along with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706429/get-first-letter-of-each-word) but I am getting an array to string conversion error.

Basically a user has a "name" which could be first name or first name and last name.  So the $str could be any of these:

```
John
John Doe
John Doe-man
John Doe Jr.
etc..
```

In this instance, I would like the output from my function to be something like `J` or `JD` depending on if their name is one word or multiple words like the sample above.  How would I accomplish this? Is there any regex I can run to also strip out things like periods, dashes or underscores just in case?

Here is my function, the problem with this is it is expecting the name to have spaces which is not always the case

```
if(!function_exists('get_avatar')){
    function get_avatar($str){
        $words = explode(' ', $str);
        $acronym = '';
        foreach($words as $w) {
            $acronym .= $w[0];
        }

        $avatar = preg_split("/[\s,_-]+/", $acronym);
        return $avatar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you're using preg_split() function?

Comment: What is unclear about the question?  Not sure why I received a downvote for my question

Comment: well... I did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the substr(); function.

```
if(!function_exists('get_avatar')){
    function get_avatar($str){
        $acronym;
        $word;
        $words = preg_split("/(\s|\-|\.)/", $str);
        foreach($words as $w) {
            $acronym .= substr($w,0,1);
        }
        $word = $word . $acronym ;
        return $word;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting an array to string conversion error.  In this instance it is because someones name is "Billy" (no spaces to explode) while another users name could be "John Doe" or "John Doe-Sr."

Comment: i edited it, try that, 
Your second bit of code was turning it back to an array.

Comment: using this way if something is a conjoined word with a hyphen it sees it as one, but any separate word is treated indivually,

you can use `strtoupper()` on the turn to make it all uppercase if you wish

Comment: alternative, if you want to remove hyphens too, change out explode for a preg_split ie.
`if(!function_exists('get_avatar')){
function get_avatar($str){
    $words = preg_split("/(\s|\-)/", $str);
    foreach($words as $w) {
        $acronym .= substr($w,0,1);
    }
    $word = $word . $acronym ;
    return $word;
}
}`

Comment: Still having trouble.  Using your code I get the error `undefined variable: $acronym` and `undefined variable: $word`.  I tried to fix these but then I still get the `array to string conversion error`

Comment: https://www.tehplayground.com/4St2ZNwUCePVUYcv

Here, play with that, this also removes '.' (full stops)

There, i defined $word and $acronym at the start.

Comment: The link was very helpful, thank you - I had the undefined variables errors due to not setting it like `$acronym = '';` instead of just `$acronym`